# JavaScript Button Click Event Requiring Two Clicks to Fire

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, buttonclick

To clarify, I have a simple slideshow using JavaScript that functions fine.

The first click on any button fires the event, but subsequent button presses requires you to click twice before they fire the *click* event.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var images = new Array();
var i = 0,
    t, f = false;

images[0] = "Image1.jpg";
images[1] = "Image2.jpg";
images[2] = "Image3.jpg";


function start() {
    if (i >= images.length) {
        i = 0;
        document.getElementById('img').src = images[i];
        i++;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('img').src = images[i];
        i++;
    }
    t = setTimeout("start()", 2000);
}

function play() {
    if (f == false) {
        f = true;
        start();
    }
}

function Stop() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    f = false;
}

function next() {
    if (i >= images.length) {
        i = 0;
        document.getElementById('img').src = images[i];
        i++;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('img').src = images[i];
        i++;
    }
}

function previous() {
    if (i >= images.length) {
        i = images.length;
        document.getElementById('img').src = images[i];
        i--;
    } else if (i <= 0) {
        i = images.length;
        document.getElementById('img').src = images[i - 1];
        i--;
    } else if (i > images.length) {

        document.getElementById('img').src = images[images.length - i];
    } else if (i <= images.length || i > 0) {
        document.getElementById('img').src = images[i - 1];
        i--;
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding top="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="previous()" />
        </td>
        <td align="center"><a href="#"><img src="Image1.jpg" id="img"/></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="next()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center" height="50">
            <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="play ()" />
            <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="Stop()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have been trying to figure out what could be causing the problem, but I do not know how to debug the code as I do not understand it.

Comment: Your if condition does not match first time. Please check by putting these values in alert inside every function, before your "if" condition. alert("i="+i+" || images.length= "+images.length);
You will get your answer.

Comment: I see the alert giving me feedback everytime that it increments... but I am not sure how that gives me the answer... sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: In `next()` you are setting `i` after updating the image (which makes first click update it to itself). `previous()` is pretty funky. You should be consistent and update `i` before setting the source, and always set the source with just `i` [not `[i-1]` or whatever].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your problem was that you incremented the counter after each function, which is wrong. By clicking previous after you click next, you are returning to the same image, which appears to you that nothing is happening. You should only increment or decrement the counter at the start of the respective function, when you need it.

Simplified your script for you. I also eliminated the useless variable `f`, and used another variable to save the array count (as it is a static array).

```
var images = [
    "Image1.jpg",
    "Image2.jpg",
    "Image3.jpg"
];
var num = images.length;
var i = 0;
var t;

function play() {
    if(typeof t === 'undefined') {
        t = setInterval(next, 2000);
    }
}

function Stop() {
    if(t) clearInterval(t);
}

function next() {
    if(++i >= num) i = 0;
    document.getElementById('img').src = images[i];
}

function previous() {
    if(--i < 0) i = num-1;
    document.getElementById('img').src = images[i];
}

// Set once on page load
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('img').src = images[0];
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/JLrDe/

Comment: I understand, thanks a bunch. I think the other responses were saying the same thing but your verbage just made more sense to me.   EDIT- I just tested it and it fixed the issue, thanks again.

Comment: Samuel, I added an array of links that match the array of images. I tried using the same variable "i" to call the appropriate link. Is there an easy way to add this functionality into the current script?

Answer (score 0):

Because you loaded the image first before you increment the `i` variable.

In that case your variable `i` is currently at `0` (which is by default picture you loaded)

So at your first click it loaded the image at index `0` (which is default picture) then increment the `i`.

and in the second click it loaded the image at index `1`

I hope it helps you